# Create multiple empty DataFrames named from a list using a loop

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm trying to create multiple empty DataFrames with a for loop where each DataFrame has a unique name stored in a list.  Per the sample code below, I would like three empty DataFrames, one called A[], another B[] and the last one C[]. Thank you.

```
import pandas as pd
report=['A','B','C']
for i in report:
    report[i]=pd.DataFrame()
```

Comment: Then you need to create a dictionary, not a list.  `report` is a list here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would be best to use a dictionary

```
import pandas as pd
report=['A','B','C']
df_dict = {}
for i in report:
    df_dict[i]=pd.DataFrame()

print(df_dict['A'])
print(df_dict['B'])
print(df_dict['C'])
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use dictionnary for that:

```
import pandas as pd
report={'A': pd.DataFrame(),'B': pd.DataFrame(),'C': pd.DataFrame()]
```

if you have a list of string or character containing the name, which is I think what you are really trying to do

```
name_dataframe = ['A', 'B', 'C']
dict_dataframe = {}
for name in name_dataframe:
    dict_dataframe[name] = pd.Dataframe()
```

Answer (score 0):

It is not a good practise, and you should probably use a dictionary to do this, but the below code gets the work done if you still need to do it, this will create the DataFrames in the memory with the names in the list `report`:

```
for i in report: 
    exec(i + ' = pd.DataFrame()')
```

And if you want to store the empty DataFrames in a list:

```
df_list = []
for i in report: 
    exec(i + ' = pd.DataFrame() \ndf_list.append(' + i+ ')')
```